# Android login button crashes app when clicked. Button validates login with Sqlite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, authentication

I am trying to make an app that has a login feature. The user enters a username and password, it is checked with a database that contains a list of acceptable usernames and passwords. If the login is successful the user is transferred to a different activity. If there is an unsuccessful login attempt, there will eventually be code that decreases an attempt_counter and locks the login button if too many attempts have been made. Before I implement the code for for just the username, I decided to test it and see if the password was being checked correctly. When I click my button to login though, the app crashes and says "Unfortunately, DrHelper has stopped." Please help me understand why this is happening. I am an amateur programmer and will gladly accept any constructive criticism.

This is my Login.java:

```
package com.example.drhelper;
/*
This class is started on application launch. It has an EditText for user name, 
an EditText for password, a TextView that is used to show the word attempts on screen,
a counter that decreases every time there is a failed login attempt, and a login button.
*/

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


//Declarations
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static EditText username;
    private static EditText password;
    private static TextView attempts;
    private static Button login_button;
    //This can be changed to increase or decrease amount of login attempts.
    int attempt_counter = 5;
    private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //This sets my layout to my activity_login.xml on create.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        //This calls my main method so that it is running then the user starts the app.
        LoginButton();
    }




    public void LoginButton () {
        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Username_Field);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Password_Field);
        attempts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_Attempts_Count);
        login_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button_Login);

        final String u = username.getText().toString();
        final String p = password.getText().toString();

        attempts.setText(Integer.toString(attempt_counter));
        /* 
         * This is the handler for my button. When it is clicked I want the username
         * and password to be checked with the id and password on the login database
         * table.
         */
        login_button.setOnClickListener(


                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        /*This is where I want to do the actual check to see if the database
                         * information matches the information that was entered into the EditText.
                         */
                        Cursor AllIDs = mDbHelper.getID();

                        AllIDs.moveToFirst();

                        while (!AllIDs.isAfterLast()) {

                        String id = AllIDs.getString(1);
                        if (id == u) {
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Username and password are correct!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //This redirects the user to the Search activity.
                            Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.drhelper.Search");
                            startActivity(intent);



                        } else {

                            if (AllIDs.isLast() && id != username.toString()) {

                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Username and password are incorrect.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }}
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.drhelper"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Search"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.drhelper.Search" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Results"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_results" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my DataBaseHelper:

```
package com.example.drhelper;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.drhelper/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "DrHelperDB";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }   

  /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
            //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

 }

 /**
  * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
  * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
  */
 private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
 }

 /**
  * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
  * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
  * This is done by transfering bytestream.
  * */
 private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

 }

 public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
     String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

 }

 @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public Cursor getID() {
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM login", null);
    return cursor;
    }

    public Cursor getPassword() {
        Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT password FROM login", null);
        return cursor;
    }

}
```

This is my LogCat from when the application is launched until the crash happens:

```
11-12 23:05:19.687: W/System(2119): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.drhelper-1/lib/arm
11-12 23:05:19.785: D/OpenGLRenderer(2119): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
11-12 23:05:19.862: I/Adreno-EGL(2119): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 09/02/15, 76f806e, Ibddc658e36
11-12 23:05:19.865: I/OpenGLRenderer(2119): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-12 23:05:28.063: D/AndroidRuntime(2119): Shutting down VM
11-12 23:05:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2119): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 23:05:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2119): Process: com.example.drhelper, PID: 2119
11-12 23:05:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2119): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor com.example.drhelper.DataBaseHelper.getID()' on a null object reference
11-12 23:05:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2119):     at com.example.drhelper.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:74)
11-12 23:05:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2119):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
11-12 23:05:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2119):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
11-12 23:05:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2119):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-12 23:05:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2119):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-12 23:05:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2119):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-12 23:05:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-12 23:05:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2119):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-12 23:05:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2119):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-12 23:05:28.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2119):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Can you post the Log cat here..

Comment: This is my logcat from when the application is launched until the crash.

Comment: where is the log cat? Refer here http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stackoverflow. I did an edit to my post and added it.

Comment: See here `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor com.example.drhelper.DataBaseHelper.getID()' on a null object reference` is the issue. You are calling a null Object reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mDbHelper` is null you should initialize it before calling its methods:

```
mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);//this would go in onCreate()
Cursor AllIDs = mDbHelper.getID();
```

Comment: That fixed my null error, but now my LogCat is showing this:      android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: login (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id FROM login. I know that I actually do have that table in the database because I just rechecked with SQLite DB Browser. Any ideas?

Comment: your helper does not create the db

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me solve my original problem even though I now have another problem.

Comment: Ok whats the issue now

Comment: I created my database with DB Browser for SQLite. When I created it, I saved it to the desktop so I could drag and drop it to my assets folder in my project. I'm not exactly sure if that is how I was supposed to get the database in the assets folder. My DataBaseHelper copies the database from the assets folder so that part should be good. I checked the DDMS and my database, DrHelperDB is actually listed in my data/data/com.example.drhelper/databases folder but yet it still says that the table does not exist. I'm not sure if the file is corrupt or if moved it to assets wrong.

Comment: Thats not the way to do it, your app should create the database. Your app users wont be connected to your desktop.